# Anylogic schedule not using the last value in the table

Tags: anylogic

In Anylogic, I am trying to make agents arrive based on a set schedule. For that, I have created a schedule. I have set the table and the time and value values correctly. However, Anylogic seems to ignore the last value imported in my table. How do I fix this?

[the schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAzEI.png)

[the corresponding table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRf3W.png)

[the schedule settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyKqq.png)

I have tried to put an empty value in the final row . While it seems to fix the problem, it says that
erval start time shouldn't be negative: -201600000 in the console when I try to run it

Comment: You should probably switch to "Intervals", not "Moments", no? How would you create agents from moments? May fix the issue as well...